# Displaying XML data in textbox through C# in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, xml

I am currently working on an application that lets the user pick an order for a restaurant. When the user clicks the order and they click submit, it should add to the XML file called "order.xml" which is what happens. However at the same click whatever has been inputted in the file should then be displayed back into a textbox on the same view. I am getting an error marked "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the code shown below...

```
var order = from MenuInfo in doc.Descendants("MenuInfo")
                       select new
                       {
                           Data1 = MenuInfo.Element("Data1").Value,
                           Data2 = MenuInfo.Element("Data2").Value,
                           Data3 = MenuInfo.Element("Data3").Value,
                       };
```

Could you help me debug this as I am at a stomp.

Full code sample

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("order.xml");
        XElement root = new XElement("MenuInfo");
        root.Add(new XElement("Data1", mealListView.SelectedValue.ToString()));
        root.Add(new XElement("Data2", _seat));
        root.Add(new XElement("Data3", buttonTable1.Text));
        doc.Element("MenuInfo").Add(root);
        doc.Save("order.xml");

        var order = from MenuInfo in doc.Descendants("MenuInfo")
                       select new
                       {
                           Data1 = MenuInfo.Element("Data1").Value,
                           Data2 = MenuInfo.Element("Data2").Value,
                           Data3 = MenuInfo.Element("Data3").Value,
                       };

        summaryTextBox.Text = "";
        foreach (var MenuInfo in order)
        {
            summaryTextBox.Text = summaryTextBox.Text + "Meal: " + MenuInfo.Data1 + "\n";
            summaryTextBox.Text = summaryTextBox.Text + " Seat ID: " + MenuInfo.Data2 + "\n";
            summaryTextBox.Text = summaryTextBox.Text + " Table ID: " + MenuInfo.Data3 + "\n";
        }

        if (summaryTextBox.Text == "")
            summaryTextBox.Text = "No Results.";
```

Comment: @Darren It says from "select new code" is where the errors throws up. Unfortunately, because I am new to C# I am not too familiar with how to debug this code.

Comment: Put a break point where you save your XML and then please add a representative sample of its structure to your question - that would definitely aid investigation. I've made an educated guess for my answer though.

Comment: did my answer help in any way? It would be useful to know whether it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what the problem is, but I think it might be related to the following.

You create a new element called `MenuInfo` as the `root` variable:

```
XElement root = new XElement("MenuInfo");
```

Later you then append this new element to another element in the XML also called `MenuInfo`:

```
doc.Element("MenuInfo").Add(root);
```

So now you probably have an element called `MenuInfo` with a child element called `MenuInfo`, like this:

```
<MenuInfo>
    <MenuInfo>
        <Data1>one</Data1>
        <Data2>two</Data2>
        <Data3>three</Data3>
    </MenuInfo>
</MenuInfo>
```

In your subsequent selection, you will select the parent `MenuInfo` element which does not have any `Data1`, `Data2` or `Data3` child elements, so when you then do

```
select new
 {
     Data1 = MenuInfo.Element("Data1").Value,
     Data2 = MenuInfo.Element("Data2").Value,
     Data3 = MenuInfo.Element("Data3").Value,
 };
```

you're trying to access the `Value` property on an element that doesn't exist.

You may be better off trying to locate the `MenuInfo` element in your XML immediately after loading and if it doesn't exist then create it. Otherwise just append the `DataN` elements to the element that already exists.